# How to avoid "Argument 1 to "join" of "str" has incompatible type "Callable[[], List[str]]"; expected "Iterable[str]"

Tags: python, mypy

A minimal example to reproduce this error could look like this

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import List


class Stuff(Enum):
    A = 'something'
    B = 'something_else'
    C = 'even_more'
    
    @classmethod
    @property
    def important_stuff(cls) -> List[str]:
        return [cls.A.value, cls.C.value]


print(f'{", ".join(Stuff.important_stuff)}')
```

That prints

```
something, even_more
```

as expected.

When I test this file with `mypy` I receive

> error: Argument 1 to "join" of "str" has incompatible type
> "Callable[[], List[str]]"; expected "Iterable[str]"

What exactly causes this issue and how could I avoid it?

Comment: decorators are the problem causing this

Comment: I think it's `mypy` not knowing how to handle the "class" created by `EnumMeta`. If you don't subclass `Enum` (and drop the `.value` attrbutes in `important_stuff`), `mypy` has no problem. (I put "class" in quotes because `EnumMeta` does quite a few things differently from `type`.) Statically, `important_stuff` is not a list; it's an instance of `classmethod` that wraps an instance of `property`, and it's the `property`'s `__get__` method that returns a list. All of that is stuff that happens at *run time*, so `mypy` has to be programmed to know about it at compile time....

Comment: ... and subclassing `Enum` seems to interfere with that hard-coded logic.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks, makes sense. Do you see a way to retrieve the same output using an implementation accepted by `mypy` or should I then just accept these errors for now?

Comment: If nothing else, you can try `", ".join(cast(Iterable[str], Stuff.important_stuff))`. It might be worth reporting this at https://github.com/python/mypy/issues; I didn't see anything that seemed to cover the same issue.

Comment: @chepner: [This one](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6700) was linked in a comment earlier (which was deleted again). Would you still recommend to open a new one (happy to do so, but also don't want to spam them)?

Comment: I would; I've posted an answer demonstrating the same kind of class property working with a non-`Enum` class.

Comment: Actually, accessing the property from the class seems to be the problem; I can reproduce the error with a non-`Enum` class, and `mypy` is happy with the same property accessed via an instance of `Stuff(Enum)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a case where `mypy` needs some hard-coded logic to deal with the class method. `mypy` can handle the same `classmethod`-wrapped property on an ordinary class just fine.(Well, almost. You need an *instance* of `Stuff`, rather than the class itself, to invoke `important_stuff`.) The `Enum` subclass also appears to work as long as you access the property via an instance of `Stuff` rather than the class itself.

```
$ cat tmp.py
from enum import Enum
from typing import List


class Stuff:
    A = 'something'
    B = 'something_else'
    C = 'even_more'

    @classmethod
    @property
    def important_stuff(cls) -> List[str]:
        return [cls.A, cls.C]


print(f'{", ".join(Stuff().important_stuff)}')

$ mypy tmp.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

If that's the case, and until `mypy` is fixed, you can explicitly cast the value as an `Iterable[str]`.

```
from typing import cast, Iterable


print(f'{", ".join(cast(Iterable[str], Stuff.important_stuff))}')
```